# C# Panel is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a main menu and when I click one of the buttons the menu panel should hide and the clicked one should open. This works for one button, but for my second it doesn't. Well, it shows the panel I guess, but it is empty, even though I have something in the panel.

The code is pretty simple, so I don't see where the problem is

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        menu_botStrip.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm tt");
        panel_startMenu.Show();
        panel_informationService.Hide();
        panel_customerManagement.Hide();
}

private void btn_informationService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel_startMenu.Hide();
    panel_informationService.Show();
}

    private void btn_customerManagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        panel_startMenu.Hide();
        panel_customerManagement.Show();
    }
```

Comment: @Michael Since I click back on the information_service to get to the menu back again, it will get hidden. And when I chose customerManagement from the main menu it still doesn't work

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure that you did not put the second panel inside the first panel. If you dragged the panels from the toolbox, there is high probability of this.

To make sure, open the `Document Outline` window (View->Other Windows->Document Outline), and look at the relation between panels. Make sure that they are not contained in one another. They must be at the same level of nesting.

If it is like this:

[image: Wrong]

then select the inner panel and press the left arrow button above the window. Then it should look like:

[image: Right]

which is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... How do I prevent that?

Comment: You can also use UserControls to design their content separately - and add them by code to the parent form.
This does not help if you put them by hand to the designer because you can accidently add userControls to another userControl, too - but it helps while working on their contents:

Comment: I lost half an hour prior to finding your post. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, after so many search that was the easiest way to find the problem (at least for me).
I created new panels, labels etc draggin from Toolbox menu and was linked as child, by code I was hiding the parent but wasn't able to show childrens, only after moving with **Document Ouline**

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be the first panel (information service) be hidden again? Maybe there's an ugly overlay if both are shown at the same time ...

```
private void btn_informationService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel_startMenu.Hide();
    panel_customerManagement.Hide();
    panel_informationService.Show();
}

private void btn_customerManagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel_startMenu.Hide();
    panel_informationService.Hide();
    panel_customerManagement.Show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @MD.Unicorn, you must be careful about ordering those panels on your form (layer context). This means that if your panel contains another panel or panels - after hiding specific parent you will hide and all child components also.